# Remap MX Keys Right Option/Control to Right Command on Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, keyboard-layout

I have a Macbook Pro M1 and use Polish layout to input Polish diacritics (łąęóńśćź) which are input using Right Option key + {key} on Macbook's internal keyboard. I have a Logitech MX Keys external keyboard and when I connect it to my Macbook Pro, Right Option key is under Right Control key which makes it ridiculously cumbersome to input polish diacritics because I need to use my pinky finger instead of my right thumb. I tried remapping the keys using Karabiner but it doesn't work. I verified using EventViewer that the keys that I want to remap are `right_option` and `right_command`. I have Logi Options+ software for Logitech hardware and I disabled the option `Always keep the keyboard in Mac layout` but it didn't help either. How can I remap the keys?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that I needed to enable the device first, then the key mappings started to work.

Comment: Enable in Karabiner -> Devices -> MX Keys -> Modify Events (see pic below since this comment can't contain an image)

Comment: Jedi, perhaps you would like to mark this as the answer.  That's the right thing to do even on questions you asked.

Answer (score 1):

I made this a separate answer so I could show a picture of how to enable event modification on the MX keyboard in Karabiner.

Karabiner -> Devices -> MX Keys -> Modify Events[image]